# Retaining variable value at the same VC but clear the value after changing VC ObjectiveC

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, instance-variables

My `Classes VC` have a segmented control on the top with different dates. When user click on the dates, it will load the content according to `dtDate` and call `LoadClasses` method.

Now I have another `Search VC`, When clicked on search, it will pass as `string` to `Classes VC` I am using `NSDefault for key txtURLFromSearch` to save the `string` and callback `NSDefault for key txtURLFromSearch` at `Classes VC`

After that, I equate the string to `sURLFromSearch` and I wish to retain it at `Classes VC` But when ever user dismiss this VC, I wish to clear the stringvalue of `NSDefault` for key `txtURLFromSearch`

I will use sURLFromSearch to do some checking and it will either append and load sURL or just default sURL.

What I am trying to achieve:

1. When USER exit the `Classes VC` how to clear `NSDefault for key txtURLFromSearch`
2. Is there a better way to push and pass data from `Search VC`to `Classes VC`. The string will retain at `Classes VC` but when user dismiss `Classes VC` it is clear all the string values from `Classes VC`?

[image: Pic]

```
@synthesize sURL;
@synthesize sURLFromSearch;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    dtDate = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [self setupSegmentButtons];

    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/YYYY"];
    sDtDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:now];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    sURLFromSearch = [defaults objectForKey:@"txtURLFromSearch"];

    NSLog(@"=====%@******",sURLFromSearch);

    [self LoadClasses];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    //=== Is there something I need to do here?
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{

    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    //=== The following doesn't work, when I switch back to this View, 
    //=== It will set txtURLFromSearch to Empty String. 
    //NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    //[defaults setObject:@"" forKey:@"txtURLFromSearch"];
    //[defaults synchronize];
}

- (void)LoadClasses {

    NSLog(@"======sURLFromSearch====%@**********", sURLFromSearch);

    if ([sURLFromSearch length] !=0 ) {

       //=====sURL 1=======
       sURL = [sURL stringByAppendingString:sURLFromSearch];

       NSLog(@"==== sURL1: %@ ", sURL);

    } else {

       //=====sURL 2=======
       sURL        
    }

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:sURL];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
[webView setDelegate:(id<UIWebViewDelegate>)self];

UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
[refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(handleRefresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[webView.scrollView addSubview:refreshControl];

}

- (void)handleRefresh:(UIRefreshControl *)refresh {

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:sURL];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
    [refresh endRefreshing];
}
```

## From Search VC where I pass the string.

```
- (IBAction)btnSearch:(UIButton *)sender {

    sURL = @"From Search, append to Classes sURL";

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:sURL forKey:@"txtURLFromSearch"];
    [defaults synchronize];

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UITabBarController *tabView = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"profileView"];
tabView.selectedIndex=1;
    [self presentViewController:tabView animated:YES completion:nil];

    Classes *vc = [[Classes alloc] init];
    [vc fromSearch:sURL];

}
```

Comment: in viewdidload you get sURLFromSearch or get null?

Comment: Replace string `sURLFromSearch = [[NSString alloc] init];` with `sURLFromSearch = @"";`

Comment: @RB1509 I get null;

Comment: than share code where you pass sURLFromSearch.

Comment: @HansheungCheah You don't do anything before ` `viewDidLoad` is called and of course, `sURLFromSearch` will be `nil`. There are too many problems in your code.

Comment: try my update answer.

Comment: @HansheungCheah you pass here surl right?

Comment: Yes sURL is a string. I am trying to pass from `Search VC` to `Classes VC` and manage to recall at `Classes VC`

Comment: can you see me you SS of code where it give warning or error please ?

Comment: you are trying to pass data into searchbar which contain in classes. Right?

Comment: not search bar just passing a string from a search page to classes

Comment: @RB1509 what do you mean by SS of code? currently it doesn't give any errors, just that i don't know `how or where` to clear the `NSDefaults value for key txtURLFromSearch` so that when user move to other `VC` and come back the `txtURLFromSearch` will be an empty string and trigger to load the default content.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169831/discussion-between-rb1509-and-hansheung-cheah).